# Wrong File String for fopen?

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have a text filed called fun on my desktop, but when I pass:

```
FILE* fp;

if((fp = fopen("/Users/<username>/Desktop/fun", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("File didn't open\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

fp is null. I have also tried

```
/home/<username>/Desktop/fun
```

and many variations, and I still can't seem to get the right file path.I am new to using files and C. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can u show us the code ?

Comment: `FIlE*` should be `FILE*`

Answer (score 6):

`fopen()` can't expand shell keywords.

Change

```
FILE* fp = fopen("~/Desktop/fun.txt", "r")
```

to

```
FILE* fp = fopen("/home/<yourusername>/Desktop/fun.txt", "r")
```

Characters like `'~', '*'` are interpreted by the shell and expanded.

Comment: so I got the next line: FILE* fp = fopen("/home/<yourusername>/Desktop/input.txt", "r") but it do not open it. What I do wrong. but if I change it to freopen(/Users/<yourusername>/Desktop/input.txt", "r", stdin) it works well

Comment: @wm.p1us, what error do you get? Try to get error with `perror()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `~` in pathnames to represent the user's home directory. That notation is recognized by shells and some other applications, but it's not part of the Unix filesystem interface. You need to spell out the user's actual home directory.

```
fopen("/home/username/Desktop/fun.txt", "r")
```

Answer (score 3):

The `~` in the path is probably the issue. It's your shell that expands that on the command line. `fopen` doesn't invoke a shell to do substitutions on the path, you'll need to do that yourself.

So pass a complete (relative or absolute) path to `fopen`, not something that requires shell expansions (`~`, globbing patterns or shell variables).

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand `~`.  Use `getenv("HOME")`.

`getenv` at [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html) even provides some code:

```
const char *name = "HOME";
char *value;
value = getenv(name);
```

Comment: I see your link to `POSIX.1-2004`, and raise you a link to `POSIX.1-2008`. [The `getenv()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getenv.html). I also upvote you for having provided any link at all to documentation.

Comment: But also note that the `value` should be `const`, because it's explicitly forbidden to modify the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*===exphome===([o]i)==================================================
 * if SIn is not NULL then
 *    if SIn starts with '~'
 *    then expands $HOME, prepends it to the rest of SIn, and
 *         stores result in SOut or, if SOut==NULL, in a new
 *         allocated string and returns it
 *    else if SOut!=NULL
 *         then copies SIn into SOut and returns SOut
 *         else returns duplicated SIn
 * else returns NULL
=*===================================================================*/
    char *exphome(char *SOut, char *SIn)
    {char *Rt= NULL;
     char *envhome= NULL;

     if(SIn)
        if(*SIn=='~' && (envhome=getenv("HOME")))
          {Rt= malloc(strlen(SIn)+strlen(envhome)+1);
           strcpy(Rt, envhome); strcat(Rt, SIn+1);
           if(SOut) {strcpy(SOut, Rt); free(Rt); Rt= SOut;}
          }
        else if(SOut) {strcpy(SOut, SIn); Rt= SOut;}
        else Rt= strdup(SIn);

     return Rt;
    } /*exphome*/
```

and then

```
fopen(exphome(NULL, yourfile), ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the answers have prompted edits of original problem.  However, as it is currently written there is NO extension on the file name?  Is this really true? or does the file end in "*.txt" etc.?

Answer (score -1):

Double-check that you have the correct full file path. Go to the file, right-click on it and select "properties". Are you entering in the path **exactly** as it is shown, including any suffixes? I.e. if the file is called "file.txt", make sure you include the ".txt" suffix in your code.